# Can i add google map autocomplete to my EditText?

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, android-edittext

I have a search EditText in my app and I want to add all address to this EditText from google map with an Autocomplete.

I want exactly how can I do it.
Thank you!

```
EditText adress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adress);
```

Comment: No. autocomplete can be casted to EditText and not to TextView, like this:

((EditText)autocompleteFragmentFrom.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input));

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes you're right but i want import all adress from google map

Comment: Whatever address you type in autocomplete edit text and when you select a place, then you need that address? is this your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

```
            AutoCompleteTextView placeAutoSearch;
            ArrayList<String> placesList;
            ArrayAdapter<String> placesListAdatper;
            String placesURL;
        String PLACES_BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?";


        placeAutoSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                    {
                            placesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                            updateList(s.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                    {

                    }
                });

    private void updateList(String place)
        {

            String parameter = "input=" + place + "&types=geocode&sensor=true&key=" + PLACES_API_KEY;

            placesURL = PLACES_BASE_URL + parameter;

            ((MapForAddressActivity)controller).getPlacesList(placesURL);

        }

        public void updatePlacesList(ArrayList<PlacesNameEntity> list)
        {
            placesList.clear();

            for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
            {
                placesList.add(i, list.get(i).getDescription());
            }

            placesListAdatper = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placesList)
            {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    android.widget.TextView text = (android.widget.TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    return view;
                }
            };

            placeAutoSearch.setAdapter(placesListAdatper);
            placesListAdatper.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



public void getAddressLatLong(String addressString)
    {
        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getBaseActivity());
        List<Address> address;
        LatLng latLng = null;

        try {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(addressString, 5);
            if (address == null) {

            }
            Address location = address.get(0);
            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );
            userLatLng.setLat(location.getLatitude());
            userLatLng.setLon(location.getLongitude());
            mMap.getGoogleMap().clear();
            mMap.drawMarker(latLng);
            ((MapForAddressActivity)controller).hideKeyboard();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Get Places List from server (Google places API)

```
public void getPlacesList(String parameter)
    {
        ((ServiceFactory) serviceFactory).getProviderService()
                .GetPlacesNameList(parameter)
                .enableRetry(false)
                .enqueue(new ServiceCallback(this, this)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void onSuccess(Object response, int code)
                    {
                        ((MapForAddressActivityView)view).updatePlacesList(((PlacesNameResponse) response).getList());
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onFailure(String errorMessage, int code) {
                        showToast(errorMessage);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Your interface for Retrofit:

```
@GET()
ServiceCall<PlacesNameResponse> GetPlacesNameList(@Url String url);
```